# Hibernate OneToMany relation with non primary key one side and EmbeddedId on other side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to build a strange OneToMany relationship (for legacy reasons). Relationship should be on `i` which is a normal column for class `P` and part of the primary key for class `B`.

Below approach works only if I create P objects, put them in the B objects (`b.setP(p)` for all bs) and set all Bs into the P object (`p.getBs().addAll(bList)`).

However, if I save a P object without any Bs, when I do a `P p1 = session.get(P.class, p.getSI())` I get the following exception which doesn't make any sense to me. Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem altogether?

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   java.lang.String field
>   com.s.s.components.P.i to
>   java.lang.String

```
@Entity
public class P {

  @Id
  @Expose
  @ValidUniqueId
  @NotEmpty
  @Column(nullable = false)
  String sI;

  @Expose
  String i;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "p")
  private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();  
}

@Embeddable
public class IPT implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "i")
  private String i;

  @Column(name = "pT")
  private PT pT;
}

@Entity
public class B {
  @EmbeddedId
  private IPT iPT;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("i")
  @JoinColumn(name = "i", referencedColumnName = "i", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private P p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `referencedColumnName` to `referencedColumnName = "sI"` because this is the id of P

Comment: But `sI` and `i` doesn't contain the same information. `p.i` should be same as `b.i`

Comment: foreign key should refer to a key , either primary key or unique index ... I don't know if `i` is unique or not

Comment: And what about data in the database ... No wrongly inserted duplicates?

Comment: Or u r trying to insert a Picture that has existing  i